# Stack Overflow RSS feed request limit

Tags: discussion, feed

Just installed Tiny Tiny RSS reader on my server. I added five Stack Overflow feeds to it.

The C# feed is not working, but the rest are. I can open the C# feed perfectly on my home computer using the exact same URL. However, when the server tries to fetch it (every 30 minutes), it comes back with a HTTP error 400. The other four Stack Overflow feeds work perfectly though.

So I'm wondering if the Stack Overflow RSS feeds have a limit on how many requests it will allow from a single IP?

The C# feed URL I am using is: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c#

Comment: Pretty sure they have limits so that you can't duplicate the content..

Comment: This wouldn't surprise me. _Everything_ on Stack Exchange is rate limited in some way.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you *sure* you're using that URL? Because that'll produce active C questions. You might prefer http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23, which is active C# questions. You might even want http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%23&sort=newest, which will give you the *newest* C# questions.

Comment: @Shog9 your 100% right, i should have been using %23. My bad!

Answer (score 4):

Needed to use c%23 in the url instead of #. Doh!

Comment: This Answer does not provide an answer to the question asked. It it shows how the situation which prompted you to ask the question, your C# feed not working, was resolved, but not by finding an answer to the question. Correcting that issue should have been an edit to the question, and perhaps a comment, not an answer. This answer is not useful to people who view the question looking for an answer to the stated question.